# GKE - Assign pod to node with gpu or cpu

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE cluster v1.19 that has a deployment that can run on GPU or CPU only nodes.

I have 2 node pools, both preemptive so nodes can be unavailable:

1. GPU
2. CPU Only

I wish to use the GPU node pool as long as GPU nodes are available. If there are no available GPU nodes I wish to assign those pods to a node with CPU only.

My current yaml for the deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: NAME
  namespace: NAMESPACE
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: NAME
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: NAME
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-preemptible: "true"
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 100
            preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator
                operator: In
                values:
                - nvidia-tesla-t4
      containers:
      - name: NAME
        image: IMAGE
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 28.0Gi
            cpu: 3000m
          limits:
            cpu: 4000m
            nvidia.com/gpu: 1
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: nvidia.com/gpu
        operator: Exists
```

The above yaml allows the pod to be assigned to a GPU node but not to a CPU node. Correct me if I am wrong, I have to set `limits: nvidia.com/gpu: 1` in order to use the gpu, but this requires the node to have nvidia.com/gpu so it can't be assigned to CPU only node.

How can I achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your question is regarding the set up of GPU before using the `limits` command. Kindly check below steps and guides on Kubenetes with GPU.

Creating New [Zonal](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus?hl=en#gpu_zonal_cluster) / [Regional](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus?hl=en#gpu_regional_cluster) cluster with GPU

[Installing NVIDIA GPU device drivers](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus?hl=en#installing_drivers)

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/nvidia-driver-installer/cos/daemonset-preloaded.yaml`

Using node auto-provisioning with GPUs \

> `gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME --enable-autoprovisioning \ --autoprovisioning-scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute`

To learn more about auto-provisioning, see the [auto-provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning) page.

You can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus?hl=en#installing_drivers) for more guide related to GKE GPU.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this.  GKE automatically taints GPU nodes with `nvidia.com/gpu` and `NoSchedule`.  So without the toleration, a pod cannot be scheduled on a GPU node.  (Note that GKE automatically adds the toleration to pods which have limit set for `nvidia.com/gpu`).

You best bet here is to either enable the cluster autoscaler or to [enable node auto-provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#using_node_auto-provisioning_with_gpus).  At least this way, new nodes will be added to the cluster as needed (and available).  Of course the number of nodes that can be added with depend on your GPU quota.